# How do you register custom methods like those within Application.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am wondering how to register custom method within:

```
Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
```

Like:

```
/**
 * Get the current application name.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this['config']->get('app.name');
}
```

Taken from:

```
/**
 * Get the current application locale.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLocale()
{
    return $this['config']->get('app.locale');
}
```

Where should I put this, instead of vendor file ofc?

Thanks

Comment: Could you just extend the `Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` class to a created class? Or make an abstract class extending `Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` ?

Comment: where would you create such a class? do you have a working example?

Comment: I'm actually not sure of what you want. Do you want to do some override on that `getName()` function?

Comment: getName is custom made one, it should not be added in vendor file but registered somewhere else and where I am asking, locale one is in vendor already and it will be there always on composer update but if I add other ones they wont be there, i need to keep them as well by registereing them somewhere else

Comment: It depends where you want to use this function. I guess you could put it anywhere you want, just make a class extending `Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` and add a getName() function and use this one?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe able to extend the `Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`

example:

```
 <?php 

 namespace app\Custom;

 class Application extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 {

 }
```

for more details, please refer this [click](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/extending-laravels-application/) here .

Note: Adding your code under vendor files, may lost during the `composer update` command. So its not advisable to actually add your custom codes there.